# Serverless Postgress - Connection terminated unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, serverless, serverless-framework

I was trying to build a function that saves data to the database when called, I am using a serverless framework and Postgress. When doing so I am getting the following error. The error is happening when I call the CreateUser function

```
POST /signup (λ: signup)
    Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Work/Learning/CWJ MicroServices/cwj-serverless-nodejs/user-service/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:73)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:625:28)
        at Connection.emit (node:events:511:28)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Work/Learning/CWJ MicroServices/cwj-serverless-nodejs/user-service/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:62:12)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
        at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:334:12)
    (λ: signup) RequestId: 02ec07bb-c20a-411c-adea-9db11d368c4c  Duration: 209.11 ms  Billed Duration: 210 ms
```

My Code as follows,
userRepo.ts

```
import { UserModel } from "../models/UserModel";
import { DBClient } from "../utility/databaseClient";
export class UserRespository {
  constructor() {}

  async createAccount({ email, password, salt, phone, userType }: UserModel) {
    const client = await DBClient();
    await client.connect();
    const queryString =
      "INSERT INTO users(phone,email,password,salt,user_type) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING *";
    const values = [phone, email, password, salt, userType];
    const result = await client.query(queryString, values);
    await client.end();
    if (result.rowCount > 0) {
      return result.rows[0] as UserModel;
    }
  }
}
```

databaseClient.ts

```
import { Client } from "pg";

export const DBClient = () => {
  return new Client({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "root",
    database: "user_service",
    password: "root",
    port: 5433,
  });
};
```

What could be go wrong here? Docker too working fine
[image]